# illegal command error code 127 in php exec function

Tags: php, exec

I am using this php code:

```
exec("unrar e file.rar",$ret,$code);
```

and getting an error code of illegal command ie 127 ... but when I am using this command through ssh its working ... because unrar is installed on the server ... so can anyone guess why exec is not doing the right stuff?

Comment: just a thought: is file.rar definitely in the same directory that the php script is running in? And is unrar in a directory that is in the PATH?

Comment: yeah file.rar is in the same directory ... unrar is installed on the system ... is there any specific ath it should be to be executed by php exec?

Comment: I told its working fine on terminal which i m using through ssh

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using the direct path of the application (/usr/bin/unrar of whatever), it sounds like php can't find the application.

Comment: I have to agree it sounds like the directory containing the unrar binary is not included in the PATH var so using a direct path should help, or just adding the binary to the directory if the path cannot be found.

Answer (score 8):

If you have chrooted apache and php, you will also want to put /bin/sh into the chrooted environment. Otherwise, the exec() or passthru() will not function properly, and will produce error code 127, file not found.

Answer (score 4):

Since this comes up as a top answer in google, I wanted to share my fix:

The simple fix I had was to disable safe_mode in the php.ini file

```
; Safe Mode
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode
safe_mode = Off
```

Comment: Safe mode has been removed from PHP as of version 5.4.0. http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

Answer (score 2):

thanx all for your response!!

I tried this

`//somedir is inside the directory where php file is
chdir("somedir");
exec("/home/username/bin/unrar e /home/path/to/dir/file.rar");`

and now it returned no exit code ... oher commands are doing file .. i tried mkdir etc .. :s

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else still gets this problem, take a look at the post here:

http://gallery.menalto.com/node/2639#comment-8638

Quote:

> I found the problem. The problem was my security-paranoid OpenBSD. When upgrading from 3.1 to 3.2 they added:
>
> - Apache runs chroot'd by default. To disable this, see the new -u option.
>
> The chroot prevented Apache from accessing anything outside of a directory, so I moved everything into the apache directory including netpbm. Everything was accessible and executable, but I guess it was still in some sort of "safe mode" because the exec() always returned 127.
>
> Anyway, running httpd with the -u option went back to the less secure non chroot'd apache startup, which allowed the exec() to work again.

Answer (score 0):

ohkiee guyz thanx ... and yes there might be some errors with $PATH ... but with given full path its working :)

`exec("/home/user/bin/unrar e /home/user/xxx/yyy/file.rar");`

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the solution for my problem of the same type so sharing what was the cause of it in my Linux setup.
For whatever reason I needed an apache module loaded before other modules and so apache was started with LD_PRELOAD. As exec inherits the environment of the parent process LD_PRELOAD was used for starting the exec-ed program (through sh). Now the preloaded module uses some bindings to apache functions and of course they are not to be present in sh. The result of the php exec was an exit status of 127. The solution was to have in my php file a putenv("LD_PRELOAD") that gets executed before any exec calls.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32406056)