# php exec() returns 127 code

Tags: php, exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [illegal command error code 127 in php exec function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438618/illegal-command-error-code-127-in-php-exec-function)

I am facing this problem: php `exec()` always returns 127 code. I tried this simple script:

```
exec("ls", $output, $error);
print_r($error);
print_r($output);
```

It returns

> 127Array ( )

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Exec just executes an external program.

Try `system()`

https://www.php.net/system

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but still no luck it also returns same code 127