# Using Exec to convert images with ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to use an exec command in php on mamp to do some stuff with imagemagick. The code runs fine from the command line:

```
convert "fullpathhere/pdfconverter/IM-wireframes.pdf" "fullpathhere/pdfconverter/converted/output.png"
```

This does what it should do - converts the pdf in to images...so I know everything is installed correctly...but as soon as I put it in to php:

```
exec('/Applications/MAMP/bin/ImageMagick-6.7.3/bin/convert "fullpathhere/pdfconverter/IM-wireframes.pdf" "fullpathhere/pdfconverter/converted/output.png"', $arr, $output);
```

it doesn't work...the $output var returns 127....which I think is path not found...but the path is correct because it runs on the command line just fine.

Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm guessing that whatever is in `fullpathhere` is not valid. Try `chdir()`ing to the same directory you were working from in the terminal, and run the exact command you were running at the terminal.

Comment: You might find answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438618/illegal-command-error-code-127-in-php-exec-function

Comment: hi, thanks for the replies.@daverandom: I run the exactylsame test using same paths on the command line and it works...it something to do with running it via the exec command.

Comment: @codler. Yes have seen that post already. I am pointing the exec to the convert using the full path...have amended the code above to show this

Comment: I'm actually getting this error in the logs dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/ImageMagick-6.7.3/bin/convert
  Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 10.0.0 or later, but libX11.6.dylib provides version 9.0.0 - not go a clue what this means!