# Exec() not executing certain files (Code 127)

Tags: php, exec

I have a php program that is using exec() to execute a program. Exec() is returning 127 as the $return parameter.

Here's the PHP code:

```
    $exec = exec('./scan', $output, $return);
    echo "<br />-----whoami-----<br />";
    echo exec('whoami');
    echo "<br />-----$exec------<br />";
    echo $exec;
    echo "<br />-----$output----<br />";
    print_r( $output );
    echo "<br />-----$return ---<br />";
    print_r( $return );
```

I get this back:

```
    -----whoami-----
    apache
    ------Exec------

    ------output----
    Array ( ) 
    ------return ---
    127
```

I know that exec() is working in my setup though, because I can call a python script that is sitting in the same folder as the file I attempted to open above, with the exact same permissions. For example this code:

```
    $exec = exec('python test.py', $output, $return);
    echo "<br />-----whoami-----<br />";
    echo exec('whoami');
    echo "<br />-----$exec------<br />";
    echo $exec;
    echo "<br />-----$output----<br />";
    print_r( $output );
    echo "<br />-----$return ---<br />";
    print_r( $return );
```

Returns:

```
    -----whoami-----
    apache
    ------Exec------
    test.py runs!
    ------output----
    test.py runs!
    ------return ---
    1
```

Any idea what might be going on? I can run the python program, but nothing works though "." I've tried other exec commands such as "ls", and they run fine. I've checked out [illegal command error code 127 in php exec function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438618/illegal-command-error-code-127-in-php-exec-function), and turned php's safe mode off. Could it be because Apache is chrooted and does not have permission to access this file? How can I fix that?

Comment: can you show the source code of `scan`?

Comment: `scan` is a compiled C++ program that works when I invoke it from the server command line with `./scan`

Comment: The c++ program `scan` links in the tesseract library `-ltesseract` at compile time. I think this is to blame. How can I give apache access to this library?