# nodejs command not executing through PHP on Linux

Tags: php

The problem is faced while running node command (which generates PDF file for given link) on Linux through PHP exec/passthru/system functions. Actually, I am trying to create PDF file through headless chrome using Puppeteer node module. Everything worked fine in Windows system but as soon as the same code was moved on production server (which uses Linux), the exec/passthru commands began to throw 127 return code errors. Please note that same node command works without any problem when run directly on terminal . 
     Also, Apache has write permissions in directory where file is being generated and command was also tried by giving the absolute paths but nothing seems to be working
The format of command is like this
    "node script-generating-code.js http://www.url-of-page.com/"

Comment: Well, it sure *sounds* like a PATH issue; compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438618/illegal-command-error-code-127-in-php-exec-function

Comment: What about chdir() first ... has that been tried, to give node its expected working directory?

Comment: No, as I have explained, the command doesn't even work when full path of node is given

Comment: I understand and read that, but have you tried chdir() first?

Comment: I will try that when I will be back in office :)