# Exec command returns 127 error code

Tags: php, linux, exec

To maket simple, i have a linux script that call a php script with only a zip command :

> My bash file :

```
#!/bin/bash
  php zip.php
```

> My PHP file zip.php :

```
<?php
exec("zip file.zip file_1.pdf file_2.pdf file_n.pdf",$aOut,$errorCode);
```

This is what i get :

- Executing the zip command directly from a bash script runs with 4000 pdf files passed in 2nd parameter.
- Executing the zip command from a PHP script (with the exec function) falls down with 4000 pdf files passed in 2nd parameter and return a 127 error.
- Executing the zip command from a PHP script (using the exec function) runs well with a small number of pdf files passed in 2nd parameter (less than 1500 files).
- Executing the zip command from a PHP script (through the exec function) runs if i put * in 2nd parameter even if i have 4000 pdf targeted by the symbol *.

I see that its not the command not found error beacause it runs well with a small number of pdf files but its something related to the length of the 2en parameter or the entire command.

Someone can help please.

Comment: why use PHP at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [illegal command error code 127 in php exec function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438618/illegal-command-error-code-127-in-php-exec-function)

Comment: I have a bigger app. I put this to simplify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the maximum length of a command line is 65535 bytes. I don't know why your command line test worked, maybe you've tried it with short filenames but one full command cannot exceed this limit.

The reason I found your question is because I was calling a command line with a heredoc as standard input, and well, the length of a heredoc can easily run away so I rewrote the call using popen() but that doesn't help you. I haven't worked with the zip utility yet, but a quick look at it's manpage says it appends files to existing archives so you should be able to split your command lines after every 64k if you want max efficiency, or after every 100 or even every single file if you want a simple algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Error Code 127:

127 means "command not found"

or

apache user has no permission to execute the command

### Solution

The solution is to make sure that the command your are using can be found within your $PATH. If the command is not in your path either include it or use absolute full path to it.

or

Give apache user permission to execute command

Comment: The problem is that when i execute the command from PHP file but with few files it runs. When i give thousend files it crash. So i don't think that its permissions

Comment: Problem you have told is error code 127 the reason is provided and if you want more specific solution provide more information about error details. How to get error details is another question and answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
exec("zip file.zip file_1.pdf file_2.pdf file_n.pdf >/dev/null 2>&1 &",$aOut,$errorCode);
```

`>/dev/null 2>&1 &` will run this command in background. and php just send command to linux

Comment: Same error..with short file nomber it runs well, but from larger number it breaks

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Friend,
>   It seems the PHP is not getting the file path or file doesn't have permission.