# php exec() returning 127 error where command running in terminal working fine

Tags: php, node.js, terminal, exec

I an trying to run this code in my server

```
exec("node -v", $out, $err);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);
print_r($err);
```

Its returning only 127.But npm, node js all installed in my server.
Even if I trying to run node -v in my terminal its returning the version.

Please suggest what can be the issue for this.

Comment: Your code works perfectly and returns the node version. It has given output as:Array
(
    [0] => v8.11.1
)
0

Comment: Please add screenshot of the output.

Comment: how exactly are your running this script

Comment: use the full path to the `node` installation & possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438618/illegal-command-error-code-127-in-php-exec-function

Comment: I am just hitting this link http://www.designedsite.co.uk/raffleticket/testnode.php in browser.

Comment: @Edwin Thanks ..its working man!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I have used this solution

```
exec("../../bin/node -v", $out, $err);
```